# Что значит фактор упорядоченности в методе Sort и как его использовать?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сортировка

Реализуйте метод Sort. Известно, что потребители метода зачастую не будут вычитывать данные до конца

```
/// <summary>
/// Возвращает отсортированный по возрастанию поток чисел
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputStream">Поток чисел от 0 до maxValue. Длина потока не превышает миллиарда чисел.</param>
/// <param name="sortFactor">Фактор упорядоченности потока. Неотрицательное число. Если в потоке встретилось число x, то в нём больше не встретятся числа меньше, чем (x - sortFactor).</param>
/// <param name="maxValue">Максимально возможное значение чисел в потоке. Неотрицательное число, не превышающее 2000.</param>
/// <returns>Отсортированный по возрастанию поток чисел.</returns>
IEnumerable<int> Sort(IEnumerable<int> inputStream, int sortFactor, int maxValue)
```

Не могу понять, что значит фактор упорядоченности и как его использовать

Comment: Вероятно нужно прочитать внимательно: "Если в потоке встретилось число x, то в нём больше не встретятся числа меньше, чем (x - sortFactor)"

Comment: @Andrew Возможно я не могу понять саму формулировку. Как я это могу использовать?

Comment: это полуотсортированный список. Допустим у тебя есть сортФактор = 5. Допустим тебе встретилось число 11. Это значит что теперь тебе не встретится число ниже чем 6 пока ты будешь дальше идти по списку.

Comment: @Andrew понял, спасибо

Comment: @Andrew, о, похоже я алгоритм примерно понял...