# методе Sort имеется фактор упорядоченности, подскажите, пожалуйста, как его использовать?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, .net, сортировка

[Что значит фактор упорядоченности в методе sort и как его использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340391/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-sort-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8CZ)

Есть похожий пост с объяснением, что за фактор упорядоченности, но всё ещё остался вопрос: Как это использовать.

Гугл молчит, а у самого допереть не получилось...

Comment: В приведенной вами ссылке есть указание на это, **это полуотсортированный список.** т.е. его легче сортировать, т.к. как только вы встретите число больше чем X, вы можете быть уверены что чисел меньше чем X более не будет, а значит вся часть списка до этого момента отсортирована и более в сортировке не участвует(можно не обращаться к первой части данных)

Comment: Что за метод? Что именно он сортирует? Не знаю в .NET таких методов, дайте ссылку на документацию.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков получается, что в описании sortFactor'а "x - это сортФактор", а не "х минус сортФактор"

Comment: @aepot это не метод .net'а, это метод, которой я должен сам реализовать, и нужно использовать все его сигнатуры